Can I define a return type in TypeScript based on the values of an array property?
I'm trying to define a function's return type based on the values in an array property of an object.
Here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:
type Table = { columns: { name: string }[] };
const table = { columns: [{ name: 'col1' }, { name: 'col2' }] };

const fn = (table: Table): Record<????, any> => {
    // some logic
};

const result = fn(table);
// Expected behavior:
result.col1; // should be accessible
result.col2; // should be accessible

Is there a way to achieve this in TypeScript?
It's similar to the approach proposed in this answer, but that solution only seems to work if I pass the array directly as a parameter to the function. In my case, the array is nested within an object (table.columns),
Thanks in advance.

You can't do it without changing table's declaration to keep track of "col1" and "col2", such as with a const assertion. The approach I'd take looks like this playground link. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?

To make this work you should use as const for exact typing and use property access syntax:
Playground
type Table = { columns: { name: string }[] };
const table = { columns: [{ name: 'col1' }, { name: 'col2' }] } as const satisfies Table;

const fn = <T extends Table>(table: T): {[K in T['columns'][number]['name']]: any} => {
    return 1 as any;
}

const result = fn(table);
// Expected behavior:
result.col1; // should be accessible
result.col2; // should be accessible


The following seems right:
type Table = { columns: { name: string }[] };
const table = { columns: [{ name: 'col1' }, { name: 'col2' }] } as const satisfies Table;

type Subkey<X> = X extends { columns: Array<{ name: infer Y }> } ? Y : never;

type R = Subkey<typeof table>
declare const fn: <T extends Table>(table: T) => Record<Subkey< T>, number>;

const result = fn(table);
result.col1; // is accessible
result.col2; // is accessible
result.whoopsieDoodle; // <-- not accessible


Looks like a lot of work to get Record<string, any>, so result.whoopsieDoodle is also accessible

@jcalz — That’s the type of table; if you want something else, use as const in the way Alexander Nenashev explained.

That doesn't help. The type of the return value of fn is always Record<string, any>. Why go through the trouble of defining Subkey? How does this differ from saying "just use string in place of ???"? And what advantage would you say this has over the other answer posted above? Is there any situation in which I'd want to use this over the other one?

@jcalz — it’s not enough to define the type of table properly; you have to use that type, and not the Table type.  I have re-written the code in the answer to clarify.

So now your answer is the same as the other one, yes?

@jcalz — I think my answer was always the same as the other one.  We typed them in at the same time.

I can look at the edit history of this and see that originally fn was not generic and unconditionally returned Record<string, any>. I'm not sure in what sense the two answers were "always the same".
